# how to select a record from an array with shape eg (10,103)

Tags: neural-network, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Hello consider an array with as shape (10,103)
The content is as follows

```
A=[[ 0.54791709  0.54943806  0.55004389 ...,  0.55054129  0.55054109
   0.55054601]
 [ 0.45400955  0.45505433  0.45480845 ...,  0.4555305   0.45553331
   0.45553635]
 [ 0.66672558  0.66327062  0.66624759 ...,  0.66594688  0.6659449
   0.6659411 ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.69362838  0.693958    0.69394086 ...,  0.69512919  0.69512934
   0.69512978]
 [ 0.44799209  0.45074033  0.44861442 ...,  0.44922826  0.44923215
   0.44923314]
 [ 0.46524247  0.46462676  0.46453131 ...,  0.46502923  0.46502886
   0.46502859]]
```

How do I succeed to select eg: the 4th record from that array, or any other record?

Answer (score 0):

You just index it, Because you have an array with 10 rows and 103 columsn ,

`data = np.zeros((10, 103))`
performing `data[4]`  will give you the elements of the 4th Row.
To generalize `data[n]` will give you the nth element.

Hope this helps